# Move folder content from one directory to another

Tags: powershell, batch-file, vbscript

I have a tinkerer that would like to move the contents of several users local files to a new directory on the server.

Move from `c:\users\%username%\appdata\roaming\filezilla`
to `C:\users\$username.mydomain\appData\roaming\filezilla`

How could I accomplish this?  batch file, vb script, power shell?  I need something quick and easy that basically copies the content.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry. I missed the part about moving multiple users. Deleting my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Something like

```
for /d %%U in (C:\Users\*) do (
  robocopy /MOVE "%%U\AppData\Roaming\Filezilla" "C:\Users\%%~nU.mydomain\AppData\Roaming"
)
```

maybe?

Answer (score 0):

I agree with [Joey](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17369465/1630171), `robocopy` is probably the best solution here. You can use it in PowerShell, too:

```
$subFolder = "AppData\Roaming\Filezilla"
Get-ChildItem "C:\Users" | ? { $_.PSIsContainer } | % {
  $src = Join-Path $_.FullName, $subFolder
  $dst = Join-Path $_.FullName + ".mydomain", $subFolder
  robocopy $src $dst /move /e
}
```